# Refresh youtube embed code using PHP, Ajax & a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, textbox, youtube

So I've been wondering about this for a while.

I'm creating an Edit site for my project, and on this edit site I want the people who have access to the page be able to paste

- /watch?v=`sometext`

into a text box, and have a preview embed player take this string and display the new player for them without loading another page or before they actually submit the URL to the Database.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function()
{
    var url = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    if (url !== "")
    {
        var video_id = url.split('v=')[1];
        var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
        if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
            video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition); 
        }

        document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id;
    }
};
```

That will strip the videoID from an url and play it in a iframe (the one you can get from the share button).

Look at the full example, and paste a full youtube video on the textbox.
http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/URcWZ/

Comment: With a little editing I finally got it working. Cheers mate. Any ideas on how to make it so that you do not have to "submit" the preview? I.e; if you type in 11 characters, symbols and numbers (the exact lenght of a Youtube link) and unfocus the textbox - it'll automatically do these changes, as if I was to press the button.

Comment: Just implement the blur event of the text box. Although YouTube urls can change and be bigger than that.